# Pytest should only collect python files with specific filename

Tags: python, pytest

I'm new to pytest and I need help with the collection of test files in my repository.
The current file system looks like this

```
pyproject.toml
src/
   module_one.py
   module_two.py
tests/
   test_module_one.py
   test_module_two.py
```

If I ran `pytest .` now, pytest is collecting all python files in my project with this result:

```
=================== test session starts ===================
src/module_one.py s                                  [25%]
src/module_one_test.py .                             [50%]
src/module_two.py E                                  [75%]
src/module_two_test.py .                             [100%]
```

The reason I ran pytest over the whole project and not only the `tests` directory is that I want to rearrange the file system like this:

```
pyproject.toml
src/
   module_one.py
   module_one_test.py
   module_two.py
   module_two_test.py
```

The file system is much bigger and more complex, as in this example. I want to have a better overview of the file structure so I can see, which python files as a responding pytest file.

I already tried to put this option in my `pyproject.toml`, but it did not work.

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_files="test_*.py"
```

By default pytest should only collect python files that have a syntax like `*_test.py` or `test_*.py`. So I'm a bit confused why it is collecting all python files in the project.

Another solution would be to add `addopts="-k '_test'"` to the `pyproject.toml`. Problem with this solution is, that `-k` also includes class / functions names and I only want to exclude it to filenames.

At the moment the `pyproject.toml` looks like this. The `norecursedirs` option is only excluding two directories in the project.

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
minversion = "6.0"
addopts = "--black --cov --isort --asyncio-mode=auto --strict-markers --durations=5 -p no:bandit"
filterwarnings = ["ignore::DeprecationWarning"]
qt_no_exception_capture = 1
norecursedirs = [ ... ]
markers = [ ... ]
```

Maybe some of you have an idea. I'm running on `pytest version 7.0.1` and updating to the newest version of `7.4.2` did not solved the problem.

Comment: Could you include Pytest's output in your question? Based on my test using version 7.2.1 it works exactly as you want even without changing the default configuration.

Comment: Hello, why do your codebase require the testing artifacts inside the `src/` directory?, that seems odd to me.

Comment: Added the output and I hope it helps. I should also mention, atm my file system is still looking like the top one, were the files are still stored in the `test` directory. When I then make `pytest` the output is the same where pytest is also testing the `src` directory files, which are not test files.

Comment: @FrancoGil the `src/`directory is much bigger and more complex and I want a better overview which python files have a testfile and which not.

Comment: The current version of pytest is [7.4.2](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/). Please update and try again, maybe your version has a bug.

Comment: Are you sure the config file is active i.e. does it print out `configfile: pyproject.toml` when you run your tests?

Comment: @Tzane yes, pytest is using the `pyproject.toml` file. If I put the option with `addopts="-k '_test'"` it works fine, but I'm still confused why `python_files="*test_.py"` is not working.

Comment: Please remove or delete `pyproject.toml`. It is really not needed for what you want to do. The default behaviour of finding files is enough.

Comment: @hbhbnr The `pyproject.toml` file itself I cannot delete, because there are settings for other packages inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution
It is super simple and I'm kinda embarrassed that I did not see it earlier. Pytest was collecting all files from my project because I activated `isort` and `black`. Then pytest is collecting all files and controlling them with these two packages. By disabling them in the `pyproject.toml` pytest was only collecting the test files.

I found the solution by just running `pytest --collect_only` and realized that because of these two packages, all files were collected.

Thanks to all for their great help and time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Make sure the pattern matches your filenames. All these patterns should work for you, tested with the example files from below:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_files="**/*_test.py"
```

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_files="src/*_test.py"
```

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_files="*_test.py"
```

But these patterns you mentioned will not work, because they do not match:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_files="test_*.py"
```

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_files="*test_.py"
```

**Old answer, still valid:**

You do not need to configure anything, pytest is normally only checking Python files starting with `test_` or ending with `_test`.

From the Good Integration Practices document, section [Conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery):

> `pytest` implements the following standard test discovery:
>
> - [...]
> - In those directories, search for `test_*.py` or `*_test.py` files, imported by their test package name.
> - [...]

Please first update pytest to its current version [7.4.2](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/), remove the `tool.pytest.ini_options` option, and then try again.

Here is the most simple example to show that what you requested will work out of the box:

```
# src/module_one.py
def one():
    return 1
```

```
# src/module_one_test.py
import module_one
def testOne():
    assert module_one.one() == 1
```

```
# src/module_two.py
def two():
    return 2
```

```
# src/module_two_test.py
import module_two
def testTwo():
    assert module_two.two() == 2
```

Result from just running `pytest` without any config file:

```
============================ test session starts ============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.12, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: <...>
collected 2 items

src/module_one_test.py .                                              [ 50%]
src/module_two_test.py .                                              [100%]

============================= 2 passed in 0.00s =============================
```

Please note that I renamed your directory `scr` to the better fitting `src`. Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with Python 3.10.12 and pytest 7.4.2.

Comment: I have updated to `7.4.2`, but the problem is still there. With and without the `tool.pytest.ini_option` pytest is collecting all python files in my filesystem. The strange thing now is, that while with `7.0.1` pytest was collecting all non-test files and then just skip them, pytest is now testing them all.

Comment: @TheNerdlyGentleman, we need to see your source code to help. Do you have a GitHub repository we could check?

Comment: thanks for the reminder with `src` :-). In case of the source code. The source code is from my company and I'm not allowed to show it to you. I know that makes finding the problem much more harder :-/. One thing I was thinking is, that maybe the `__init__.py` files could be the problem, that pytest is collecting the non-test files?

Comment: That is very unlikely. Are you sure you are using pytest 7.4.2 now? What does `pytest --version` show? Could you please extend you initial question with the updated test report from pytest?

Comment: Yes pytest is showing the newest version `7.4.2` but still keeps collecting all python files in my project. It is really odd, why pytest is doing it.